# Force download a file using PHP through ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I need to convert a result of a MySQL query to an xls file, force download the file using a PHP script, and call the script through ajax, but I could not seem to achieve it. I could not download the file for some reason. What could it be that I am missing?

**convert.php**:

```
        //getting the results of my query goes here
        //
        //
        //converting the results to xls file and force downloading it goes below...

        $output .= '</table>';
        header("Content-Type: application/xls");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls");
        echo $output;
```

**Ajax:**

```
<script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">
        function convert() {


            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {


                if(this.readyState == 4) {

                    xhr.close(); 

                }
                if(this.status == 200){

                    alert("Success!");


                }
            }

            xhr.open("POST", "convert.php", true);

            xhr.send();

        }
    </script>
```

I only get the "Success!" part working, but no file download. `convert.php` is working fine if i run it normally using `HTML form` alone (not through ajax). Thank you in advance for helping!

Comment: The point of Ajax is that the responses is *handled by JavaScript*

Comment: Store post data into session in first AJAX request then use window.open("https://domain-name/convert.php"); inside AJAX response.  and destroyed the POST session after the file download code execution